# Sitecore Experience Editor never stops loading

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

On my local instance of Sitecore 9 update 2, when I view a page in the Experience Editor, the loading graphic appears and never goes away. The underlying page is visible. However, the Experience Editor's ribbon is not shown.

Has anyone experienced this? How did you correct it?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me on the vanilla Sitecore site which by default uses the Sample Layout based on ASP.NET Web Forms (i.e `.aspx` and `.ascx` files). I meant to use MVC, hence the default layout was incompatible, and as soon as I created a `.cshtml` file and my MVC  layout item in admin, the problem has gone.